# How to alternate row colour in UITableView

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview

Say I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell containing 4 labels, would there be a way to, upon loading the cells into the view with a basic layout, edit them based on the row number that they are in. In my example I would need every other row's text label's text to have one colour, and the other to have a different colour. I am already pretty sure that my answer would involve something like:

```
bool true = (int) indexpath.row %2 != 0
```

And then I would set an if statements that changes the colour based on the boolean value. The only thing I don't know is what method I would have to put this in the TableViewSource and how I would be able to access the specific cell's contents and not *every* cell's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Get indexpath of specific row:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowNumber, inSection: 0)
```

Reload specific cell of the tableview:

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

Get specific cell of and changes done:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Comment: What method would I be doing this in, because doing it in the viewdidload method would imply that the cells haven't even been added in yet? And even if I can get the cell, which I have no trouble in doing, how do I edit the components that are in that cell, specifically, and not just every single cell?

Comment: You are setting custom colour in the label on different cell by clicking or while loading? if changes in colour on clicking of the table then set code in didselect of the tableview delegate method

Comment: It is not for when you click on the cell, it is just meant to be there from when the view is loading, therefore there is no good place to put it, as I can't explicitly put it in the custom layout, as the layout disregard's row count and has no way of accessing it.

Comment: Then you need to set on runtime then you create a one function like func getCell(indexPath : Indexpath)
{
//put the code get a cell of that Indexpath
}
and call from cellfor:Indexpath

Comment: I can get the cell, I need to know how to edit that specific cell's components

Comment: cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) //define class type
here is your cell you can access any label of that cell. after just reload

 tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)

Comment: Yes that is not the problem. The problem lies in editing the cell that has then been gotten

Comment: cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) //define class type here is your cell you can access any label of that cell. after just reload tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)

Comment: This is not a helpful answer, as I asked the question and tagged it as a c# question, but you seem to have answered in objective-c. In your previous comment you say "You can access any label of that cell". How can I access any label, as there are no functions to do that in terms of a custom tableviewcell